# How do we change this function to support multiple arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class SampleClass
{
  public:      
    int test(int ... arguments)
    {
        cout << arguments[0] << endl; // Access first element in array
        return sizeof(arguments);
    }
};

int main()
{   
   SampleClass lol;       
   cout << lol.test(3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0) << endl;       
   return 0;
}
```

The `test` function fails due to my limited understanding in C++ semantics. But how can I fix it so that it can access the FIRST element in the arguments lits and then return the size of `arguments`?

---

As @Nik pointed out, I could obviously pass in an array, but there is no real fun with that! I am trying to do this just for learning - to see if this is even possible in C++.

Comment: @ForEveR Basically, make an argument list and be able to access them.

Comment: Can you not pass a list or vector to the func??

Comment: @Nik. Yes, but I am trying to avoid that purely for educational purposes.

Comment: Class `Derived` has nothing to do with the root of your question, is that a fair assessment ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Absolutely! I was testing some other things and forgot to rename the classes. In fact, I have updated the question to remove that. Good eye!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're all guessing at what you want, I'll throw in:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
size_t test(Ts ... arguments) {
    auto unused = { 0, ((cout << '[' << arguments << "]\n"), 0)...};
    (void)unused;
    return sizeof...(arguments);
}
```

which works with different types of arguments ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/974385fb722e28ba)). This solution is a bit too "clever" to be readable, though.

The trick here is to build a braced-initializer-list - the `{...}` stuff - whose elements are initialized by processing the variadic arguments in order. You then convince the compiler that said initializer list isn't used for anything, so the code will be optimized to just generate the desired side effects.

The comma operator in C++ evaluates to the value of the rightmost subexpression. The other subexpressions are evaluated and their values discarded. So `((cout << '[' << arguments << "]\n"), 0)` has the effect of dumping some stuff to `cout` - including one of the variadic parameters - and evaluates to 0. After expanding the pack with the `...` that line of code is effectively:

```
auto unused = { 0, ((cout << '[' << arg0 << "]\n"), 0),
                   ((cout << '[' << arg1 << "]\n"), 0),
                   ((cout << '[' << arg2 << "]\n"), 0) };
```

The `cout` junk is evaluated for its side effects and discarded, the whole thing is deduced as a `std::initializer_list<int>` just as if we had written

```
auto unused = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

(The extra zero is there at the beginning to avoid a syntax error if someone calls the function with *no* arguments at all.)

The `(void)unused;` line is casting `unused` to `void`. It will compile to absolutely nothing, but also will typically tell compilers not to warn us about `unused` being an unused variable.

Comment: It is clever. In fact, I can't even tell if it is using recursion. So I'll ask you directly. Is it using recursion? Additionally, how can access certain indexes in arguments?

Comment: @mk1 No, there is no recursion.

Comment: This is too advanced for me. So, how can access certain indexes in arguments? Also, can you please expand your explanation. In fact, I have changed this to be right answer!

Comment: @mk1 If you need to treat specific indexes specially, it's probably a sign that a variadic function is not the proper design. That said, if you absolutely must you can dump the pack into a tuple and access the tuple by numerical index: `std::get<1>(std::make_tuple(arguments...))`.

Comment: what do you suggest for me to access certain variables? Basically to make the code in the original question work.

Comment: @mk1 Ideally, something like the technique WhozCraig used: an initial argument pattern to match specific parameters, with a variadic pack for "everything else".

Comment: FWIW, a good idea is to just stuff this pattern of expansion behind a macro. `using swallow = int[]; #define VARIADIC_EXPAND(expr) (void)swallow{0, ((expr),0)...}`.

Comment: @Casey I made a workable solution, but it has its flaws. I have put it here (both the solution and its problem) : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a9de679400892dd

Comment: @Xeo Can you put a use case of that?

Comment: @mk1: It's exactly what Casey did at the top of this answer, except hidden behind a macro to make it more readable. Would be used as `VARIADIC_EXPAND(cout << '[' << arguments << "]\n");` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
double test( int num, ... )
{
  va_list arguments;                     // A place to store the list of arguments
  double sum = 0;

  va_start ( arguments, num );           // Initializing arguments to store all values after num
  for ( int x = 0; x < num; x++ )        // Loop until all numbers are added
    sum += va_arg ( arguments, double ); // Adds the next value in argument list to sum.
  va_end ( arguments );                  // Cleans up the list

  return sum / num;                      // Returns the average
}
```

so youre points are on the wrong side of your parameter list.
i hope this helps and goodluck.

Answer (score 3):

Hm. You are trying to mix two features of C++, `variadic-templates` and `variable-length argument list`.
Your code will not compile at all, since you have no templates here and for `variable-length argument list` declaration should be

```
int test(int arguments...)
```

and you can access values from this list with functions from `cstdarg` header.

With `variadic-templates` you can do following thing

```
class Derived
{
public:
    template<int... arguments>
    int test()
    {
       int array[] = {arguments...};
       return sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    }
};
```

use it like

```
cout << lol.test<3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0>() << endl;
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to just use `return sizeof...(arguments);`

Comment: @WhozCraig There is no reason of course, but read OP's question please.

Comment: @ForEveR I changed it from `int` to `int*` and everything just collapses. Would you know as to why this happens? I changed the template, the array type, and passed in pointers to integers. With the error `the value of 'y' is not usable in a constant expression lol.test<y>()`

Comment: @ForEveR I did, which was also why I was wondering why the variadic was in the template argument list rather than the function argument list. I'm probable just missing something in the question that you're seeing but I'm not.

Comment: @mk1 value of y should be `constexpr`... template non-type parameters should be resolved on compile-time.

Comment: @WhozCraig Probably, I'm wrong, but this deleted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235009/how-do-access-the-arguments-of-variadic-template/20235059#20235059 points me on this thought...

Comment: @ForEveR yeah, I can't tell honestly which direction is the concrete one the OP is driving for. I posted a function-parameter answer, and hopefully between that and this, (and the litany of var-args answers) all the bases are covered. +1 btw.

Comment: This feature is excellent but only exists in the most modern compilers (c++11). VS2012 can't compile this, VS2013 is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure I fully understand your question. If you want access to "the first" argument to the function rather than the template, I *think* something like this will do it for you, but I may be completely misunderstanding your purpose here:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
int foo(int arg0, Args... args);

template<>
int foo(int arg0)
{
    // here just to catch expansion
    std::cout << '[' << arg0 << ']' << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

template<typename... Args>
int foo(int arg0, Args... args)
{
    foo(arg0);
    foo(args...);
    return 1 + sizeof...(args);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(1,2,3,4,5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(100,200,300) << std::endl;

    int a=10, b=20;
    std::cout << foo(a,b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
5
[100]
[200]
[300]
3
[10]
[20]
2
```

Comment: `foo(args...);` This is what I want to avoid. It makes such simple behavior unnecessarily complex. Lets say I use this for much larger applications. I can then `static_cast` my parameters to `void*` and then `static_cast` back out - a technique that will allow for a very good use polymorphism because functions won't get built up in subclasses that use variable number of parameters. Additonally, recursive calling uses too much stack and extra cycles which are quite unnecessary in this case and especially in applications that call these functions 100s of times per second.

Comment: The method by @ForEveR is really good for smaller cases where the copy overhead is not a big issue, but if we want to provide a pointer based argument list, I don't think it will work (Unless I am proven wrong, which I am sincerely hoping somebody will)

Comment: @mk1 People could give you better advice if you post another question about what you actually want to do with this.

Comment: @mk1 ok *now* I think I understand what you're driving at. That sub-expansion is somewhat the driving force behind variadic parameter packs, but I think I see where you're going. The recursion will be unwound, I'm confident, but regardless there are likely better fitting answers then to be sure. Anyway, glad you found it at least ponderable. thx. The single expansion ForEveR has is likely a good fit.

Comment: @Casey Of course I can, but I hate when people tell me exactly what to do. Once a basic idea is given to me, I would like to come up with myself. IMHO, that teaches me more. But if I can't derive something from the answers I have gotten, I will def. post!

Comment: @WhozCraig ForEveR's answer (although I marked as correct) won't unfortunately suffice for my particular idea since I can't use `void*` without having a `constexpr` which is unfortunately too much overhead. But his does answer the question, so I gave him the best answer. Nevertheless, there has to be another way that can also deal with `void*` but I am not smart enough to come up with it quickly :( Maybe you can help!

Comment: @mk1 heh. there are *plenty* of people on this site with significantly more populous rabbits in their proverbial variadic template hats than I. I'll give it more thought, but don't be shocked if one of them ponies up the answer you're *really* looking for long before I do. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Here is a solution using a very simple idea. I have commented the issue with it however. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70e185d1192e7246

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1) use an ellipse (only way to have unlimited arg list):

```
int foo(int a1, ...);
```

Your code will need to parse the ellipse like printf does. you'll be limited to builtin C types.

2) Use multiple templates:

```
template<typename T1> int foo(T1 a1);
template<typename T1, typename T2> int foo(T1 a1, T2 a2);

// more templates for more arguments

This method us used, usually up to 10 parameters (10 template functions)
```

3) Use a function with defaults or illegal values so you'll know which is the last valid argument:

```
 int foo(int a1, int a2 = -1, int a3 = -1, int aN = -1);
```